# How convert PostgreSQL Array to JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript, type-conversion

How to convert PostgreSQL Array in string eg. `"{1,2,3,4}"` to javascript/typescript array: `[1,2,3,4]`.
The values in the array must be a number type.

I tried a solution with *replace* and *split* but it returns string values.

```
var test = "{1,2,3,4}";
test = test.replace("{", "");
test = test.replace("}", "");
//test = test.replace(/\{|\}/gm, "")  //regex replace
test.split(",")   //['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: You should not have to do this. The postgresql driver should do it for you. Which one are you using ?

Comment: u can replace curly brackets with square then use JSON.parse method. like this `JSON.parse(test.replace("{", "[").replace("}", "]"))`

Comment: @DenysSéguret I do not have access to what the entire backend does.

Comment: @shajji I know, I just wanted to show all the steps I'm doing.

Comment: Fixing the backend would probably be the right solution but I know not all projects are ideally managed...

Comment: PostgreSQL supports JSON type I recommend you use that, it's more efficient and there's no reason to incorrectly format an array in it

Comment: sorry i don't get it, can u please tell me what do u mean by 'show all the what i'm doing'

Comment: @shajji Show everything i did step by step :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cleaner solution not involving building a JSON string just to parse it:

```
test = test.match(/[\w.-]+/g).map(Number)
```

But when dealing with a database you're usually not supposed to parse the data yourself unless you're writing the driver (but there are already good ones for postgresql).

Answer (score 1):

I find solution with JSON.parse but this also need *replace* before conversion.

```
var test = "{1,2,3,4}";
test = test.replace("{", "[");
test = test.replace("}", "]");
JSON.parse(test)  //[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Test with building a string for array size: 100000~900000: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gavnpg

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.parse("[" + test.slice(1, test.length-1) + "]")
```

Comment: Please add context to your answer explaining how this is a solution to the problem. Thanks! --From Review